# Where are the rpm files after installation using yum?

Tags: yum, rpm, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm using Red Hat 5.4.

I have installed a package using yum the package was wireshark.

However, after it has installed. Where can I find the rpm package?

I would like to locate the actual wireshark.rpm package so that I can install it on another machine that is not connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look under `/var/cache/yum` directory.

They should be there unless you have some kind of autocleanup going on. If you do, try this command:

```
find /var/cache/yum -iname '*.rpm'
```

If there's nothing there, see the cachedir variable in `/etc/yum.conf` and check out what's the current directory for storing packages. It can also be that tmpwatch or some other daily cron cleanup has cleared the `/var/cache/yum`.

Answer (score 29):

The rpm cache directory location can be found in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
```

You should change the `$basearch` and `$releasever`, values based on your red hat release version.

If you want to keep the rpm cache after installation the keep cache value should be set 1 in:

```
/etc/yum.conf
```

set

```
keepcache=1
```

Answer (score 11):

You also can install the download only plugin for yum which causes the rpms to be downloaded to the cache directory but not installed.

`yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly`

Then use it with the `--downloadonly` flag.

`yum install --downloadonly -y wireshark`

Then you will find the rpms in the cache directory as set by your `/etc/yum.conf`

e.g `cachedir=/var/tmp/yum/cache/$basearch/$releasever`

Comment: in my case, i had to do `yum reinstall --downloadonly`

Comment: Note that the package has to be not installed at the time (otherwise yum won't do anything)

Comment: You can also download to a specific directory: `yum reinstall --downloadonly --downloaddir=SOME_DIR -y`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using yum against a baseurl where rpm are downloaded in background. You can keep the downloaded rpm which are deleted automatically after installation.

## vim /etc/yum/yum.conf

keepcache = 1
cachedir= /XXX/XXX ---> your choice

Now the downloaded rpm will be saved in the cachedir you selected. From that you can create your own repository.